# Writting php code as regex in str_replace

Tags: php, regex

directly to the point

```
  echo str_replace('</h3><table','<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>',$doc->saveHTML());
```

in the code above will the php code ( `<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>` ) excuted or not?

Comment: Why not try it and see?

Comment: not working. @Siolio.

Answer (score 0):

No, your code **won't be executed**, but you want to [escape the apostrophes](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php7p7.html). Every instance of `'` should be replaced with `\'` in your code if you type it directly as [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)  in PHP:

```
str_replace('</h3><table', '<?php echo \'Hello World!\'; ?>', $doc->saveHTML());
```

There is no need to escape anything if the code is already in a variable, is loaded from a file etc.

If you want to type your PHP code directly and you don't want to escape anything, you can use the [HEREDOC syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc):

```
$str = <<<EOD
<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>
EOD;
echo str_replace('</h3><table', $str, $doc->saveHTML());
```

---

Now, everything in quotes (`""` or `''`) is a [string](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and will **not** be executed. So **if you want the code to be executed, don't put it into quotes**. This cannot be easily explained with `echo`, but you [already told it's just a sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17988307/writting-php-code-as-regex-in-str-replace#comment26299831_17988350), so let's assume you want to use the [`rand()` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) instead.

In this case, you don't want to do this:

```
str_replace('</h3><table', '<?php echo rand(); ?>', $doc->saveHTML());
```

but all you need is:

```
str_replace('</h3><table', rand(), $doc->saveHTML());
```

The last problem is you should execute the code before you call the `str_replace` function. This will be useful if you have a lot of code you want to execute:

```
$replacement = rand();
str_replace('</h3><table', $replacement, $doc->saveHTML());
```

Comment: <?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?> is just example but how to add more php code?

Comment: @Siolio just replace every `'` with `\'` in your favourite text editor or use the HEREDOC syntax.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer but the php code <?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?> is echo as is and not excuted

Comment: I just tried it but the php code <?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?> is echo as is and not excuted

Comment: As I told you, **your code won't be executed**. If you want to execute the code, do it **before** you call the `str_replace()` function, store the output in a variable and finally replace `</h3><table` with the variable you created before.

Comment: and that what i did but still not excuted

Answer (score 0):

It's very strange to put an echo statement in a function which result is also echo'ed.
Put your code, actually its result in a variable and let it being replaced in the function:

```
$replacement = 'Hell0 World';
echo str_replace('</h3><table', $replacement, $doc->saveHTML());
```

The replacement variable can then exist of everything you want, if properly escaped off course.